# nor able to redirect from openAM

Tags: openam

My webpage is protected by a web policy agent in windows server 2008 r2.I have already created the agent profile in open-AM 12 and also given the policy.I have protected the resource "http://www.example.com:80/*", access to "authenticated user". But when i am typing in Mozilla browser "WWW.example.com/new.HTML",it redirecting me to the open-AM lo gin page.when i am giving the lo gin valid information its accessing but again and again refreshing automatically,i am not getting my webpage.please help

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem i think.Because the domain name where my openAM server is running and the domain name where my policy agent is running was not same.When i gave same domain name for both ,its started working.

Comment: If Agent and OpenAM do not share the same cookie domain, you have to configure CDSSO mode for Agents.